# How to link checkboxes to ajax xml

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, checkbox

Thanks for the help. I've managed to pull data from my xml file onto the checkboxes.
I'm just now playing with trying to get this code:

```
 $('.cb').on('click', function () {
                    nextID = $(this).attr('target');
                    nextEl = $('#' + nextID);

                    if (!nextEl.is('visible')) {
                        nextEl.show();
                    }
                });
```

to work with this:

```
$(function () {
     $.ajax({
     type: "GET",
     url: "decisionTree/xml/tree0001.xml",
     dataType: "xml",
     success: function (xml) {
     $(xml).find('content').each(function (i) {
     var ou = $(this).text();
     $('body').append("<input type='checkbox' class='cb' value='" + ou + "'>" + ou + '<br>');
                            });
                        }
                    });
                });
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks again

Comment: What is the specific problem? Are the elements created? What is `root`?

Comment: The elements are created and work. It's just getting the data from the xml file to show for each checkbox. I have seemed to confused myself, and others by the looks of things! Root was just something I was playing with on jsfiddle.

Comment: maybe this will help a bit http://plnkr.co/edit/sBi4QYrDx8bVq0Ox6lyK?p=preview